# How to run a flex duct branch through a unreachable trunk?

Tags: hvac

Have a trouble to cut a 5" inch of hole in the trunk.  I don't have space to make hole through the side of trunk. the only space is let between joists and, from where its hard to cut a hole of 5" [image: enter is it feasible ? image description here]
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: You mean without moving things it’s not reachable? Sometimes we have to make an access point cut from the inside and then seal up the access point.

Comment: @EdBeal has the right idea. I would use a good mastic to seal the access pint and not tape.

Comment: @Ed Beal, How can I make a hole in trunk which is not directly accessible. There is nothing I can move. The hole where i wan to make is almost 3 feet away from soffit's outside edge.

Comment: You better call a pro then and they will show you how to make an access point when there is limited space. The idea of an access point is cutting a hole from a different location. If you can’t access a way to do it from the inside the trunk it might require pulling a section down putting the branch up then reassembling the trunk line.

Comment: Can you show picture of place you want the hole.  Maybe if the good people here, see the access problem they might have an idea.

Answer (score 2):

Some options that come to mind are using a low profile drill to start a hole and then awkwardly cutting it with tin snips or a nibbler if you have enough space.  With a little more space you may even be able to fit a hole saw with a low profile drill.  Some "Adjustable" hole saws have shorter length than common arbor and cups.

If you really can't fit anything in there, from your picture it looks like you have access to the opposite side, so you can get a 5" holesaw and a 18-24" hole saw extension bit and drill through both sides of the duct.  Once you're done, seal the hole you don't want with a metal plate, self tapping screws and that grey duct basher goo.  That gets you a hole and just leaves you with needing to screw your flange on, which could still be a huge pain, but again a low profile drill should do the job with only 5-6" clearance.  If you don't have 5-6" clearance, you don't have room for your duct anyway, so I assume you have at least that to work with.  There may be some adhesive that is considered acceptable, but I've never seen a professional HVAC guy forego screws.

Hex head duct screws are particularly easy to work with with a magnetic bit, but an option for really hard cases is to drill a pilot hole and then put the screw in by hand with a stubby screwdriver.

Comment: I think your first paragraph is the right answer. If a 90 degree drill adapter is used that has the added benefit of reaching further into the joist cavity. Looking at the first picture with the tape measure it appears the center of the hole is 30 inches from the soffit. Even a larger person should be able to get their arms into the joist cavity far enough to reach the center of the hole with a drill using a 90 degree adapter with a low profile hole saw.  Drilling up through the bottom is also a good option.

Comment: I would prefer to go with 2nd option. First cut a bigger hole from opposite/bottom side to make the required hole to the top from inside. install a collar and duct to the top. then patch and seal the bottom hole with metal sheet. only problem is how to seal/tape the collar from the top.

Comment: @VickyP actually now that you make me think of it, a 5" hole would probably allow you to screw in and mastic the flange from the inside with aircraft bits and then all you'd have to do on the top is reach over and get a compression clamp and a wrap of tape on.  You'd need a significantly larger hole on the bottom side though unless you fold the flange to get it in and then somehow unbend it ship in a bottle style.

Comment: @K H. i didn't understand your last statement "unless you fold the flange to get it in and then somehow unbend it ship in a bottle style" ?

Comment: @vickyP If you're attaching the flange from the outside, you only need a 5" hole to make a 5" hole with a holesaw.  If you're attaching it from the inside, the bottom hole has to be large enough to fit the wide part of the flange that overlaps the edges of the upper hole.  It's sheet metal so an option to reduce total hole size is to bend it, put it in and unbend it.

Comment: Thanks I gotch you . can I use mastic sealant from inside to attach collar  ?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's allowed, but I would not use mastic alone to attach it.  Use self tapping hex head screws with a magnetic socket and extension bit and use the mastic to seal.  A cursory search would seem to indicate it's OK to use mastic on the inside of a duct although it will smell until it cures and it's less smooth so there may be extra dust buildup between cleanings.  You probably need a 5.5" hole saw to attach it from the inside for the hole the neck passes through and a 6.5-7" holes saw for a bottom hole large enough to get a flange through.

Comment: I'd try to figure out a way to install it from the outside as then you'll only need a single 5" hole saw cup.  You could hole saw both holes, then use a long bit to drill pilot holes around the top side hole and get someone to hold the flange in place while you mark those holes on to the flange.  Take the flange off and drill holes to match and then you should be able to mastic and screw it in place by reaching with a stubby screwdriver to the top side.  A trick to get the holes aligned would be to mastic the face of it and get someone to hold a few fine nails up through the hole in the duct.

Comment: You can use those to line the flange up and drop it into place, pop screws into a few other holes, then pull the nails and replace them with screws and paint some more mastic onto the outside.  Awkward to reach, but usually quite doable.

Comment: @K H, One of the HVAC guy came and said, its not good to make a hole from bottom and then patch. Why he would have said that ?

Comment: @VickyP You could ask him what concerns he has, probably because it's better for the inside of the duct to be smoother.  A duct worker would be more likely to access tools to do an awkward cut or simply take down a section of the duct temporarily.  That said, I've seen numerous wrong holes being put into ducts, and if it's prohibitively expensive to replace that section of duct, they just get permission to patch it.  If you weren't sensible about the size and location of the hole, you could decrease the rigidity of the duct.